# Sql Server 2005 Memory allocations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, memory

How do I find out the max and min memory allocated for SQL Server 2005? My sql server appears to have maxed out its memory on my box and does not seem to be doing any garbage collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 performance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147511/sql-server-2005-performance-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No SQL Server will not release Memory unless it receives pressure from OS.This is by design

Read these threads

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/90d5422f-c924-4211-9323-7373e9d5ad1f/

https://serverfault.com/questions/108192/how-do-i-get-sql-server-to-release-its-memory

However you can allocate MAX memory in SQL Server 2008.I hope this will be true for SQL Server 2005 as-well.Right click on your Server Instance in SSMS and goto properties.And then Memory.

Normally it is advised to allocate MAX memory slightly less than Physical memory of the Server.read the above threads for details.

[image]